# Stylesheet not loaded in the view

Tags: node.js, express

I have a css file inside the css folder of the public directory.

```
   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
   app.use(express.static('public'));
```

I am calling css in index.ejs file as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
```

But the style is not being loaded. From inspect element, I am getting product in url.

http://localhost:3000/products/css/style.css

Comment: try change your css link to `"/css/styles.css"` ?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your file structure I assume that your file structure looks like

- public

  - css

    - styles.css

If this is the case, make your href="/css/styles.css"
also, in your app.js include the following:

```
var path=require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname +'/public'));
```

If you do not have a public folder containing your css, I recommend making one. I believe express/ejs(one of them) looks specifically for public folders for css files. Hope this helps.